# Stats for mobile browsing as per orientation

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, statistics

Can I get a statistics of what percentage of users browse the websites with landscape mode in mobile.

I tried to google it but couldnt find the result, I wanted to know how many users I am missing by not styling my website for landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

you could try Google Analytics, you will be able to get more details about nearly everything happening in your website, Location, mobile OS, screen Sizes etc..